# PHP reading API - mandatory parameter not sent

Tags: php, api, parameters

I am getting familiar with working with APIs. I have the following question:

Error is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Larislackers\BinanceApi\Exception\BinanceApiException: [-1102]: Mandatory parameter 'timestamp' was not sent, was empty/null, or malformed. thrown in C:\Users\Francisco\vendor\larislackers\php-binance\src\BinanceApiContainer.php on line 568
```

Edit: This is the class: https://larislackers.github.io/php-binance/source-class-Larislackers.BinanceApi.BinanceApiContainer.html#276-291

I can notice it's because the TIMESTAMP is mandatory:
https://www.binance.com/restapipub.html#current-open-orders-signed

Can someone provide me an example of how would they fill the timestamp? 
This is my code so far:

```
$orders = $bac->getOpenOrders(['symbol' => 'XVGETH']);
var_dump($orders->getBody()->getContents());
```

Comment: Maybe something like: `$bac->getOpenOrders(['symbol' => 'XVGETH', 'timestamp' => time()]);`.

Comment: Hi. I am getting this error: Fatal error: Uncaught Larislackers\BinanceApi\Exception\BinanceApiException: [-1021]: Timestamp for this request is outside of the recvWindow

Answer (score 0):

Add a `timestamp` key to the `$params` array.

```
$orders = $bac->getOpenOrders(['symbol' => 'XVGETH', 'timestamp' => time()]);
```

`time()` returns the current time. If you want some other time, there are many date-time functions that can be used. It's also just a number that represents the time in seconds, you can perform ordinary arithmetic like `time() - 86400` to get the current time yesterday.

See https://www.binance.com/restapipub.html for how the Binance API uses the `timestamp` option.

Comment: Hi. I am getting this error: Fatal error: Uncaught Larislackers\BinanceApi\Exception\BinanceApiException: [-1021]: Timestamp for this request is outside of the recvWindow

Comment: Use a different time. I don't know what this timestamp represents when using the API, I assume you do.

Comment: Hi. What the timestamp states is "@option int    "timestamp"  A UNIX timestamp. (required)". Sorry, I am still very new into this

Comment: A unix timestamp is a date and time represented as a number. Functions like `time()` and `strtotime()` return timestamps.

Comment: I am trying the following but is not working. $orders = $bac->getOpenOrders(['symbol' => 'XVGETH',{'recvWindow': 10000000}]); 
Do you have an idea? I have already synchronized the clock with a time server to keep up with them

Comment: Why did you add `{}` around `recvWindow`? It should use the same `'name' => value` syntax.

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't like the current time, and the default window should be adequate. I don't know anything about Binance, I never heard of it before.